# Variadic function templates, argument order, and deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to write a variadic template function which will construct a linear combination of [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) matrices, taking advantage of the expression support. (Hence why I want to use a variadic template rather than a simple loop.)

However, I'm having a strange thing happen with the deduction of my template arguments. Here's a simplified code example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "eigen3/Eigen/Dense"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// matrix linear combination
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename Derived>
auto LinearCombination(
    const typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix,
    const typename Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar a
  ) -> decltype(a*matrix)
{
  return a*matrix;
}

template <typename Derived, typename... Args>
auto LinearCombination(
    const typename Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix_a,
    const typename Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar a,
    Args... args
  ) -> decltype(a*matrix_a + LinearCombination(args...))
{
  return a*matrix_a + LinearCombination(args...);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd m1, m2, m3;
  m1.resize(2,2);
  m2.resize(2,2);
  m3.resize(2,2);
  m1 << 1, 2,
        3, 4;
  m2 << 5, 6,
        7, 8;
  m3 << 9, 0,
        1, 2;

  std::cout << LinearCombination(m1, 2.) << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << LinearCombination(m1, 2., m2, 3.) << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << LinearCombination(m1, 1., m2, 2., m3, 1.5) << std::endl;

  // termination
  return 0;
}
```

For a reason which I don't understand, the first two function calls compile, while the third fails with

```
variadic-eigen.cpp(44): error: no instance of overloaded function "LinearCombination" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Eigen::MatrixXd, double, Eigen::MatrixXd, double, Eigen::MatrixXd, double)
    std::cout << LinearCombination(m1, 1., m2, 2., m3, 1.5) << std::endl;
                 ^
variadic-eigen.cpp(19): note: this candidate was rejected because at least one template argument could not be deduced
  auto LinearCombination(
       ^
variadic-eigen.cpp(10): note: this candidate was rejected because mismatch in count of arguments
  auto LinearCombination(
       ^
```

Is there some part of the standard which I'm missing which leaves this behavior undefined?

Comment: Comment out your second `decltype`. Here is a [simplified code](https://godbolt.org/g/kAu8Dk) to play with.

Comment: it tries to figure out return type of `LinearCombination()` for 4 params while compiling your generalized `LinearCombination()`

Comment: Ah, but I need that second `decltype` for C++11 compatibility?

Comment: No, compiler can figure return value type on it's own

Comment: `variadic-eigen.cpp(19): error: "auto" function requires a trailing return type`

Comment: huh... get a better compiler? :)

Comment: @Barry thanks for the links -- I definitely read one of those yesterday and didn't fully absorb it...

Comment: @C.M. `auto` or `decltype(auto)` appear to work with C++14, as it delays determining the return type until after the template argument deduction. I'll have to follow the other instructions and see if I can find a working C++11 solution.